# Update Statements in Stored Procedure Suquentially?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

Below UPDATE A iam updating facot Sqares table
-iam using updatd factor from the sqare table to calulate final value in Parameter
   Below UPDATE A iam updating facot Sqares table
Below UPDATE A iam updating facot Sqares table

```
DECLARE @Year   char(8) = '2017';

WITH E1 AS(
   SELECT N FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) E(N)
),
E3 AS(
   SELECT a.N FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c
),
cteTally AS(
   SELECT TOP (360) DATEADD( dd, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1), CAST(@Year AS date))  myDate
   FROM E3
),
weekDays AS(
   SELECT myDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(myDate) ORDER BY myDate) rn
   FROM cteTally
   WHERE DATENAME( WEEKDAY, myDate) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
),
    Final as(
SELECT 
 myDate StartDay,
 datename(dw,myDate) Name, 

 DATEADD(dd,19,myDate) EndDay,
   DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, myDate), 0) FirstDay
FROM weekDays
WHERE rn = 1
)

SELECT FirstDay,StartDay,Name as StartName,

case when Name='Monday' THEN DATEADD(dd,18,StartDay)
     when Name='Tuesday' THEN DATEADD(dd,17,StartDay)
     when Name='Wednesday' THEN DATEADD(dd,16,StartDay)
     when Name='Thursday' THEN DATEADD(dd,15,StartDay)
     when Name='Friday' THEN DATEADD(dd,14,StartDay)

          ELSE NULL  END AS EndDate,


          case when Name='Monday' THEN datename(dw,DATEADD(dd,18,StartDay))
     when Name='Tuesday' THEN datename(dw,DATEADD(dd,17,StartDay))
     when Name='Wednesday' THEN datename(dw,DATEADD(dd,16,StartDay))
     when Name='Thursday' THEN datename(dw,DATEADD(dd,15,StartDay))
     when Name='Friday' THEN datename(dw,DATEADD(dd,14,StartDay))

          ELSE NULL  END AS EndName
 into #Dates FROM Final
```

Comment: Please provide some example data to show what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a parameter @factor.
Alter the first statement to `set @factor =select B.candy/b.randy .....` .
Then make the updates without the joins. (Use @factor)
Debug and analyze @factor to select your work.
Alternatively you could use (nolock) in the second update but please keep in mind that you did not commit your transaction as it looks right after the last update (your "problem" looks like you are in an transaction and your first update will not be commited before the second update so you select the table again which doesn't have your update yet)

Answer (score 0):

This might occur due to datatype conversion.

please check the c. finalvalue could hold/insert/retrieve the return type of (cost*factor).

Sql server update will do its part perfect, but the datatype needs to be verified.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @StartDate date
   DECLARE @EndDate date
DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR
SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
select StartDay,EndDate from #Dates

OPEN @Cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM @Cursor INTO @StartDate,@EndDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO #Dest
select @StartDate StartDate,@EndDate EndDate, Max(high) High,min(low) Low from #Results
where date between @StartDate and @EndDate
FETCH NEXT
FROM @Cursor INTO @StartDate,@EndDate
END
CLOSE @Cursor
DEALLOCATE @Cursor
SELECT B.[open],a.* FROM #Dest A
                     JOIN #Results B ON A.StartDate=B.dATE